# Comparing numbers in a file to a console input

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program to read in a number from the console, and then read an arbitrary number of numbers from a file.  It should then print out how many times the console number appears in the list read from the file.  I am not sure how to do the second part can anyone help me with how to count how many times the number appears.  The only code I have so far is for the first part.

My idea for the second part was something like this:

```
 while(!inputfile.eof){
    if(inputfilenumber == consolenumber){
       counter = counter + 1;
  }
```

but I can't seem to put this into practice as I am not sure how it would work.

Comment: Since nothing is changing in that loop regarding `inputfile`s state or position, I don't expect that thing to end anytime soon. Secondly, avoid `istream::eof()` in almost all cases, and this is no exception to that general rule. It doesn't behave like you think it does. Use `while (inputfile >> inputfilenumber) { if (...) }`

Answer (score 0):

Sample code you can use it for reference.

```
int input;
int count = 0;
cin>>input;
ifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile.open("text.txt");
char output[100];
if (myReadFile.is_open()) 
{
  while (!myReadFile.eof())
   {          
     myReadFile >> output;
     int val = atoi(output);
     if(val == input)
      {
          cout<<"found input"<<input;
          count++;
      }

   }
}
cout<<"count ="<<count;
myReadFile.close();
```